# ¿Por qué mi formulario de Inicio de Sesión arroja el error "Este campo es obligatorio" aún cuando todos los campos obligatorios están llenos?

Tags: html, python, django

Llevo ya varios días quemando mis ojos frente al monitor y aún no logro dar con el problema aquí. Verán, tengo un formulario de Inicio de Sesión en un pequeño proyecto de Django, el cual sin importar lo que haga termina generando el mensaje "Este campo es obligatorio." sin llegar nunca a iniciar la sesión del usuario de prueba. He mirado la documentación oficial, algunos tutoriales, un pequeño libro que tengo y sigo en el mismo atasco. Os muestro un poco del pequeño proyecto.

```
# models.py
class UserLoginInfo(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verification_token = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = AccountManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Usuario'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuarios'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

```
# forms.py
class UserAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Correo electrónico'}
    ))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=8, widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Contraseña', 'data-toggle': 'password', 'id': 'password'}
    ))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserLoginInfo
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'remember_me')
```

```
# views.py
class UserAuthenticationView(LoginView):
    form_class = UserAuthenticationForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data.get('remember_me')

        if not remember_me:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
            self.request.session.modified = True
        
        return super(UserAuthenticationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', UserAuthenticationView.as_view(authentication_form=UserAuthenticationForm), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

```
<!-- Template: login.html -->
<form method="post" class="card-body text-center">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mb-4">
        <i class="feather icon-user-plus auth-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <h3 class="mb-4">Inicio de Sesión</h3>

    {% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <div id="form_errors">
            {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
            <strong>{{ value }}</strong>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Correo Electrónico</label>
        {{ form.email }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        {{ form.remember_me }}
        <label> Recuérdame</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="btn btn-primary shadow-2 mb-4">Iniciar sesión</button>

    <p class="mb-2 text-muted">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? <a href="#">Restablecer</a></p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-muted">¿No tienes una cuenta? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Registrarse</a></p>
</form>
```

[image: Error "Este campo es obligatorio." en la vista renderizada.]

Una pequeña aclaración:
Tal y como se puede ver intuir por las URL, hay definidas vistas y formularios (si aplica) para el cierre de sesión y el registro de nuevos usuarios, con respecto a este último, la lógica que emplea en la definición de su formulario, vista y plantilla es exactamente igual a lo que se muestra en los fragmentos de código adjuntos, y este funciona sin problema, lo cual no hace más que aumentar mi desconcierto con respecto al inicio de sesión. ¿Podría alguien, por favor, arrojar algo de luz sobre mis ojos y ayudarme a localizar lo que sea que esté mal en el código?

Comment: No veo nada malo a simple vista. Has probado a agregar print(form.errors) en la función form_valid() de la vista UserAuthenticationView? O el depurador de Python, me da igual. Asi puedes ver los errores del formulario cuando se procesa la solicitud de inicio de sesión. Otra cosa: estás mostrando el mensaje de error directamente usando la variable value. No tengo claro si value es una lista de mensajes de errory por tanto loq ue deberías hacer es iterar sobre value . Pero ojo, de esto no estoy muy seguro, te lo sugiero por probar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en el archivo forms.py. El formulario `UserAuthenticationForm` requiere que se completen los campos de `EmailInput` y `PasswordInput` antes de enviar el formulario. Pero no existe la logica que verifique si lo que ingreso el usuario es correcto.

En la propiedad `Meta`, has definido el modelo `UserLoginInfo`, pero este modelo no es un modelo del formulario, sino un modelo de usuario. Debido a esto, el formulario no está validando correctamente los campos y siempre muestra el mensaje de error "Este campo es obligatorio".

La solución sería eliminar la propiedad `Meta` del formulario y agregar los campos necesarios manualmente

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He probado lo que me has indicado y realizado algunos cambios al archivo forms.py, pero sigue sin funcionar. Sigo trabajando en ello. Al menos, gracias a tí, sé en donde enfocarme.